# How to disable Cloudflare Browser Insights via API or Terraform?

Tags: cloudflare, terraform-provider-cloudflare

I can not find any information about Cloudflare Browser Insights on the API documentation.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033929991-Cloudflare-Browser-Insights#5tDRl4LGok5jnHLGwuSww5

How can I disable it programatically?